# How to set app.json manifest items from the CLI?

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to set `app.json` [manifest](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema) items manually? (i.e. for an app that's already built?)

In case this is an XY problem, what I am interested in is setting `success_url` via the heroku CLI (rather than in `app.json`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these items of the manifest like addons, buildpacks, env, name ... can be changed for apps that's already built using Heroku CLI or Heroku Platform API.

Looking at the [Heroku CLI Commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands) and [Heroku Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#app-setup), there is no way to change `success_url` after the app is built even if you update `app.json` manually and rebuild the app because the `app.json` is only used to orchestrate the first time setup of the application.

Comment: I heard back from support since asking this question, and even heroku peeps knew little about `success_url`, and commented that it's very lightly documented. Based on this I think best to minimise reliance on it